# Pytest: provide id to un-parameterized test

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to have an `id` associated with any pytest that I run, be it parameterized or not. Is there a way to supply an id to an un-parameterized test, such that the nodeid appears as something like `my_test[my_id]` i.e. something consistent with parameterized tests?

Answer (score 1):

there isn't a builtin mechanism for this beyond `parametrize` -- that said, you could build a thing that ~simulates it by modifying the module-scoped name for a function:

```py
def test_thing(): pass

# need to use `globals()` since `[` isn't a valid identifier
globals()['test_thing[my_id]'] = test_thing
# delete the old test so it isn't run
del test_thing
```

```
$ pytest -v t3.py 
...
collected 1 item                                                               

t3.py::test_thing[my_id] PASSED                                          [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 0.00s ===============================
```

or perhaps a magical decorator is more your style:

```py
import sys

def name_test(testid):
    def decorator(func):
        setattr(sys.modules[func.__module__], testid, func)
        return None  # need to avoid double-discovery
    return decorator


@name_test('test_thing[my_id]')
def test_thing():
    pass
```

```
$ pytest -v t2.py
...
collected 1 item                                                               

t2.py::test_thing[my_id] PASSED                                          [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 0.00s ===============================
```

there is a ~fairly straightforward and way less hacky to do this with parametrize however:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('_', (pytest.param(0, id='my_id'),))
def test_thing(_): pass
```

this makes a single parametrize case with a custom id, the `_` is chosen because the value isn't used

---

disclaimer: I'm a pytest core dev

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot. I use `request.node.callspec.id` in a broadly-scoped fixture, which I believe only works with the less hacky solution at the end.